# Server sends emails to itself instead of to me

Tags: centos, email

CentOS 6.7 server.

When using either the Webmail or PHP mail() emails directed to me@domain.com do not get sent to my inbox for me@domain.com that I have set up with Gmail - instead they get sent to the local inbox on the server which has one email address: root@domain.com.

Why is this?

Comment: How are your  MX records configured?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Only one entry for domain.com

Comment: The local mail daemon on your server needs configuration update. Show the configuration and we can tell what to change.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen What file would you like me to show? I'm using SendMail

Comment: The server's name must not be set to your naked domain name.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What do you mean?

Answer (score -2):

If you server is also the outgoing SMTP server for PHP, it maybe trying to deliver messages local-to-local. From what you've said, it has an valid domain registered to it. Basically, your root@domain.com might be working as a domain catch-all address.

(Educated guess based on experiences with hMailServer on Win Server 2012)